# How run .sql script JDBC?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

i have .sql file with script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS groups;
CREATE TABLE groups(
group_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
group_name VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(group_id)
);
```

And im trying to run this file to create table in my PostgreSQL DB using this code:

```
    String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/school";
    String user = "postgres";
    String password = "password";

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, user, password);
    System.out.println("Success.........");
    ScriptRunner scriptRunner = new ScriptRunner(connection);
    Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/main/resources/database/dbScript.sql"));
    scriptRunner.runScript(reader);
```

but table not generating. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: do u get any error?

Comment: it prints just .sql  script contents but not creates table in my database.

Comment: What is `ScriptRunner`? Is it from a library, if so, which library?

Answer (score 0):

Add below in your sql script:--- ( you are supposed to create database first)

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = ON
CREATE DATABASE school;
use school;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS groups;
CREATE TABLE school.groups(
group_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
group_name VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(group_id)
);
```

hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: exception: CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block